# How to generating TypeScript code with SWC

Tags: typescript, rust, abstract-syntax-tree, codegen, swc-compiler

I'm hoping to use [SWC](https://github.com/swc-project/swc) in Rust to generate some TypeScript code. Unfortunately, it seems the emitter can only print JavaScript. Is this correct, or is there a way to print TypeScript? For instance, let's say we're crafting the following AST.

```rs
use swc_atoms::js_word;
use swc_common::{BytePos, Span, SyntaxContext};
use swc_ecmascript;
use swc_ecmascript::ast;

fn main() {
    let program = ast::Program::Module(ast::Module {
        body: vec![ast::ModuleItem::ModuleDecl(ast::ModuleDecl::ExportDecl(
            ast::ExportDecl {
                decl: ast::Decl::TsTypeAlias(ast::TsTypeAliasDecl {
                    span: Span::default(),
                    declare: false,
                    id: ast::Ident::new(js_word!(""), Span::default()),
                    type_params: None,
                    type_ann: Box::new(ast::TsType::TsKeywordType(ast::TsKeywordType {
                        span: Span::default(),
                        kind: ast::TsKeywordTypeKind::TsStringKeyword,
                    })),
                }),
                span: Span::default(),
            },
        ))],
        shebang: None,
        span: Span::new(BytePos(1), BytePos(1), SyntaxContext::empty()),
    });
}
```

How might I get the TypeScript corresponding to the `program` AST?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to first create a compiler (with the `swc` package not `swc_common`)

Inside your Cargo.toml dependencies add :

`swc = { git = "https://github.com/swc-project/swc" }`

```
let c = swc::Compiler::new(cm.clone());
```

Then use the print method it expose

```
let ast_printed = c
        .print(
            &ast,
            Some(filename.to_str().unwrap()),
            None,
            false,
            EsVersion::Es2022,
            SourceMapsConfig::Bool(false),
            &AHashMap::default(),
            None,
            false,
            None,
        )
        .expect("Failed to print");
```

Then you can print the `.code` field with `println!("{}", ast_printed.code);`